# Error using `should` to test nodeJS app ( undefined is not a function )

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I want test and REST API using mocha, so i have the following code to test the create operation:

```
'use strict';

var should = require('should'); 
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('supertest');  
var winston = require('winston');


describe('Routing', function() {

  describe('asset', function() {
    it('Crear un nuevo activo en la base de datos y retornarlo', function(done) {
      var asset = {
        "description"      : "Computador portatil",
        "maker"            : "Lenovo",
        "module"           : "Y410",
        "serialNumber"     : "123123",
        "bardCode"         : "21212",
        "account"          : 1212,
        "usefulLife"       : 24,
        "downtimeCosts"    : 200,
        "purchasePrice"    : 120000,
        "assetState_id"    : 1,
        "assetCategory_id" : 3,
        "assetSystem_id"   : 3,
        "supplier"         : 1
      };
    request(url)
    .post('/asset/create')
    .send(asset)
    .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          console.log (res.should.have);
          res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

the POST operation is the following:

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  models.asset.create(req.body

  ).then(function(asset) {
    res.send(asset.dataValues)  
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log (error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

When run the test get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the line `res.should.have.status(200);` I suppose that the reason was because i dont say explicit the status response so I change the res to `res.status(200).send(asset.dataValues) but don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try the following code:

```
should(res).have.property('status', 200);
```

It solves the fact that res doesn't have the property ".should".

Answer (score 1):

see http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var should = require('chai').should();
```

Comment: Hi thanks  for your answer, I install chain using `sudo npm install chai   --save-dev` and change the vars but the error persist

Comment: did you check teh URL i posted? are you using mocha runner?